# Storing client data on a server object

Tags: javascript, object

I have written a JavaScript function that I am not sure how to test, so I will just ask - Is this correct JavaScript (formatting aside)?

```
function remember($miner,quality,equals){
    var for24hrs=new Date().getTime()+86400000;
    G.pool.miners[$miner]=(!G.pool.miners[$miner])?{}:G.pool.miners[$miner];
    if(quality!=='conn'){
        G.pool.miners[$miner][quality]=equals;
        G.pool.miners[$miner]['remain']=for24hrs;
        }
    for(var miner in G.pool.miners){
        if(G.pool.miners[miner].remain < new Date().getTime()){
            G.pool.miners[miner]=null;
            }
        }
    return;}
```

The code saves a record of a connected socket (miner) on the node.js sever when ever the miner changes state. The server will remember the miner for 24hrs after. Another miner may change state and become remembered - when this happens if the first miner has not changed state in 24hrs the first miner will be destroyed.

The only time I dont wan't to remember them is when they are first connected

```
(quality==='conn')
```

It may be called like this:

```
remember('miner_bob','likes to dig',true);
remember('miner_bob','eats','sandwiches');
remember('miner_jim','likes to dig',false);
remember('miner_jim','eats','road kill');
```

G, G.pool, and G.pool.miners are all objects:

G is on the global scope to make pool accessible

G.pool has values and functions

G.pool.miners is the place to store miners in memory

Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: console.log each value you need...make some test cases, don't stay on the source only...